# Molecular Simulation: PBC using the Ewald Summation technique

Tags: rust, simulation

The following is a Rust implementation of polymer simulation where the **PBC**(periodic boundary condition) has been implemented using the *Ewald Summation* technique.

Can you review the code?

**Is the *PBC* properly implemented using the *Ewal Summation?***

```
use rand::Rng;
use std::f64::consts::PI;
use std::f64::consts::E;
use plotters::prelude::*;

const N: usize = 9;
const SIGMA: f64 = 2.0;
const PERIODIC_BOUNDARY: f64 = 5.0;
const TEMPERATURE: f64 = 2.0;
const MIN_ATOM_DISTANCE: f64 = 1.0;
const MAX_ATOM_DISTANCE: f64 = 3.8;
const SIM_STEPS: usize = 10000;
const WRITE_STEPS: usize = 10;
const EWALD_ALPHA: f64 = 0.5;

type Point = [f64; 2];

struct Polymer {
    chain_vec: Vec<Point>,
}

impl Polymer {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Polymer {
            chain_vec: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    fn plot_energies(&self, energies: &[f64]) {
        let root = BitMapBackend::new("energies.png", (800, 600)).into_drawing_area();
        root.fill(&WHITE).unwrap();
        let (min, max) = (0, energies.len());
        let (x_min, x_max) = (min as f64, max as f64);
        let (y_min, y_max) = (energies.iter().fold(f64::INFINITY, |a, &b| a.min(b)),
                              energies.iter().fold(f64::NEG_INFINITY, |a, &b| a.max(b)));
        let mut chart = ChartBuilder::on(&root)
            .x_label_area_size(40)
            .y_label_area_size(40)
            .margin(10)
            .caption("Energies", ("sans-serif", 40.0).into_font())
            .build_cartesian_2d(x_min..x_max, y_min..y_max)
            .unwrap();

        chart.configure_mesh().draw().unwrap();

        chart.draw_series(LineSeries::new(
            (min..max).map(|x| (x as f64, energies[x])),
            &RED,
        )).unwrap();

        println!("Check the output in file 'energies.png'");
    }

    fn apply_boundary_condition(&self, coord: Point) -> Point {
        let mut x = coord[0];
        let mut y = coord[1];
        if x > PERIODIC_BOUNDARY {
            x -= PERIODIC_BOUNDARY;
        } else if x < 0.0 {
            x += PERIODIC_BOUNDARY;
        }
        if y > PERIODIC_BOUNDARY {
            y -= PERIODIC_BOUNDARY;
        } else if y < 0.0 {
            y += PERIODIC_BOUNDARY;
        }
        [x, y]
    }

    fn get_distance(&self, coord1: Point, coord2: Point) -> f64 {
        let dx = coord1[0] - coord2[0];
        let dy = coord1[1] - coord2[1];
        let dx = dx - PERIODIC_BOUNDARY * (dx / PERIODIC_BOUNDARY).round();
        let dy = dy - PERIODIC_BOUNDARY * (dy / PERIODIC_BOUNDARY).round();
        (dx * dx + dy * dy).sqrt()
    }

    fn get_point_at_radius(&self, coord: Point, radius: f64) -> Point {
        let angle = rand::thread_rng().gen::<f64>() * 2.0 * PI;
        let x = (angle.cos() * radius) + coord[0];
        let y = (angle.sin() * radius) + coord[1];
        self.apply_boundary_condition([x, y])
    }

    fn morse_potential_func(&self, r: f64) -> f64 {
        (E.powf(-2.0 * SIGMA * (r - MIN_ATOM_DISTANCE)))
            - (2.0 * E.powf(-SIGMA * (r - MIN_ATOM_DISTANCE)))
    }

    fn ewald_short_range_potential(&self, coord: Point) -> f64 {
        let mut potential = 0.0;
        for (_i, &other_loc) in self.chain_vec.iter().enumerate() {
            if self.get_distance(coord, other_loc) < MIN_ATOM_DISTANCE {
                potential += self.morse_potential_func(MIN_ATOM_DISTANCE);
            }
        }
        potential
    }

    fn ewald_long_range_potential(&self, coord: Point) -> f64 {
        let mut potential = 0.0;
        for m in -5..=5 {
            for n in -5..=5 {
                let mut sum = 0.0;
                for &other_loc in self.chain_vec.iter() {
                    let dx = coord[0] - other_loc[0] + (m as f64) * PERIODIC_BOUNDARY;
                    let dy = coord[1] - other_loc[1] + (n as f64) * PERIODIC_BOUNDARY;
                    let r = (dx * dx + dy * dy).sqrt();
                    sum += self.morse_potential_func(r);
                }
                potential += sum;
            }
        }
        potential * PI / (EWALD_ALPHA * EWALD_ALPHA)
    }

    fn get_potential(&self, index: usize) -> f64 {
        let current_loc = self.chain_vec[index];
        let short_range_potential = self.ewald_short_range_potential(current_loc);
        let long_range_potential = self.ewald_long_range_potential(current_loc);
        short_range_potential + long_range_potential
    }

    fn get_total_potential(&self) -> f64 {
        let mut potential = 0.0;
        for i in 0..self.chain_vec.len() {
            potential += self.get_potential(i);
        }
        potential
    }

    fn initialize_polymer(&mut self) {
        let mut current_coord = [0.0, 0.0];
        self.chain_vec.push(current_coord);
        for _ in 0..N - 1 {
            let new_loc = self.get_point_at_radius(current_coord, MAX_ATOM_DISTANCE);
            self.chain_vec.push(new_loc);
            current_coord = new_loc;
        }
    }

    fn run_simulation(&mut self, steps: usize) {
        for _ in 0..steps {
            let rand_index = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..self.chain_vec.len());
            let old_loc = self.chain_vec[rand_index];
            let new_loc = self.get_point_at_radius(old_loc, MAX_ATOM_DISTANCE);
            self.chain_vec[rand_index] = new_loc;

            let old_potential = self.get_potential(rand_index);
            let new_potential = self.get_potential(rand_index);
            let delta_energy = new_potential - old_potential;

            if delta_energy > 0.0 {
                let acceptance_probability = (-delta_energy / TEMPERATURE).exp();
                if rand::thread_rng().gen::<f64>() > acceptance_probability {
                    self.chain_vec[rand_index] = old_loc;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut polymer = Polymer::new();
    polymer.initialize_polymer();
    let mut energies = Vec::new();

    for step in 0..SIM_STEPS {
        polymer.run_simulation(WRITE_STEPS);
        let total_potential = polymer.get_total_potential();
        energies.push(total_potential);

        if step % WRITE_STEPS == 0 {
            println!("Step: {}, Energy: {}", step, total_potential);
        }
    }

    polymer.plot_energies(&energies);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I lack the domain-specific knowledge to currently check whether *Ewald Summation* is implemented correclty. Maybe somebody else can do that.
I, however, have made some other observations about your code:

## Separate `main.rs` and `lib.rs`

You currently have everything in one unit. That's fine.
It may, however, be preferable to make your struct `Polymer` and the type `Point` public and oursource the library code, i.e. everything but `main()` into `lib.rs` in your src folder.

## Make public methods public

Currently `new()` and `simulate()` are private methods of `Polymer`. Consider making them public to have access to them when you import them in other projects or your `main.rs`.

## Separate `new()` and `default()`

Your current `new()` does not accept any of the struct's members. It *should* accept `polymer_chain: Vec<Point>`.
You can then *also* implement the `Default` trait to achieve what your current `new()` does.

## Useless casting

Casting `PERIODIC_BOUNDARY` to `f64` is useless. It is already declared as such.

## Use linters

I discovered all of the above issues by just using `cargo clippy` on your project. You should use it, too.

## Don't use `unwrap()`

...in production code. It might cause panics that will be hard to track for the end-user. Handle all errors that may arise.

## Let the functions be free

Your struct `Polymer` currently has member functions that have nothing to do with the actual polymer. Consider making them free functions.

## Use (Doc-)Tests

Testing your code for correct behaviour can make it unnecessary to ask for its correctness. Write tests for the functions that assert whether they produce the correct result. I recommend writing the tests before the functions (-> [test-driven development / TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)) so that you let your design be guided by the outcomes you want to achieve.

`lib.rs`

```
use plotters::prelude::*;
use rand::Rng;
use std::f64::consts::PI;

const N: usize = 9;
const SIGMA: f64 = 2.0;
const PERIODIC_BOUNDARY: f64 = 5.0;
const TEMPERATURE: f64 = 2.0;
const MIN_ATOM_DISTANCE: f64 = 1.0;
const MAX_ATOM_DISTANCE: f64 = 3.8;
const K: f64 = 1.0;
const SIM_STEPS: usize = 10000;
const WRITE_STEPS: usize = 10;

pub type Point = [f64; 2];

pub struct Polymer {
    polymer_chain: Vec<Point>,
}

impl Polymer {
    #[must_use]
    pub fn new(polymer_chain: Vec<Point>) -> Self {
        Self { polymer_chain }
    }
    // Perform the simulation and plot the energies
    pub fn simulate(&mut self) {
        self.initialize_polymer();
        let mut total_pot_vec = Vec::new();

        for _ii in 1..=SIM_STEPS {
            self.run_simulation(WRITE_STEPS);
            let total_pot_double = self.get_total_potential().round();
            total_pot_vec.push(total_pot_double);
        }

        plot_energies(&total_pot_vec);
    }

    // Calculate the Ewald summation of the potential energy
    fn ewald_summation(&self, index: usize) -> f64 {
        let mut real_sum = 0.0;
        let current_loc = self.polymer_chain[index];

        // Calculate the real space summation
        for (i, &other_loc) in self.polymer_chain.iter().enumerate() {
            if i != index {
                let r = get_distance(current_loc, other_loc);
                real_sum += morse_potential(r);
            }
        }

        let mut image_vec = Vec::new();
        for i in -2..=2 {
            for j in -2..=2 {
                image_vec.push([
                    f64::from(i).mul_add(PERIODIC_BOUNDARY, current_loc[0]),
                    f64::from(j).mul_add(PERIODIC_BOUNDARY, current_loc[1]),
                ]);
            }
        }

        // Calculate the reciprocal space summation
        for (i, &image_loc) in image_vec.iter().enumerate() {
            for (j, &other_loc) in self.polymer_chain.iter().enumerate() {
                if j != index {
                    let r = get_distance(image_loc, other_loc);
                    real_sum += morse_potential(r);
                }
            }

            if i < image_vec.len() - 1 {
                let r = get_distance(image_loc, image_vec[i + 1]);
                real_sum += harmonic_energy(r);
            }
        }

        real_sum
    }

    // Calculate the total potential energy of the system
    fn get_total_potential(&self) -> f64 {
        let mut harmonic_pot = 0.0;
        let mut pair_pot = 0.0;

        for i in 0..self.polymer_chain.len() - 1 {
            let current_bead = self.polymer_chain[i];
            let next_bead = self.polymer_chain[i + 1];
            let r = get_distance(current_bead, next_bead);
            harmonic_pot += harmonic_energy(r);

            for j in i + 1..self.polymer_chain.len() {
                let bead = self.polymer_chain[j];
                let r = get_distance(current_bead, bead);
                pair_pot += morse_potential(r);
            }
        }

        harmonic_pot + pair_pot
    }

    // Initialize the polymer by generating random points
    fn initialize_polymer(&mut self) {
        let mut current_point = [0.0, 0.0];
        self.polymer_chain.push(current_point);

        for _ in 0..N - 1 {
            let new_loc = get_point_at_radius(current_point, MAX_ATOM_DISTANCE);
            self.polymer_chain.push(new_loc);
            current_point = new_loc;
        }
    }

    // Run the simulation for the specified number of steps
    fn run_simulation(&mut self, no_of_steps: usize) {
        for _ in 0..no_of_steps {
            let rand_index = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..self.polymer_chain.len());
            let before_loc = self.polymer_chain[rand_index];
            let before_pot = self.ewald_summation(rand_index);
            let new_loc = get_point_at_radius(before_loc, MAX_ATOM_DISTANCE);
            self.polymer_chain[rand_index] = new_loc;
            let after_pot = self.ewald_summation(rand_index);
            let pot_diff = after_pot - before_pot;

            if pot_diff < 0.0 {
                continue;
            }

            let rand = rand::thread_rng().gen::<f64>();

            if (-(pot_diff / TEMPERATURE)).exp() > rand {
                continue;
            }

            self.polymer_chain[rand_index] = before_loc;
        }
    }
}

impl Default for Polymer {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::new(Vec::new())
    }
}

// Plot the energies using the plotters library
fn plot_energies(energies: &[f64]) {
    // Create a drawing area for the plot
    let root = BitMapBackend::new("energies.png", (800, 600)).into_drawing_area();
    if let Err(error) = root.fill(&WHITE) {
        eprintln!("Error when filling root: {error}");
    }

    // Define the range of x and y axes for the plot
    let (min, max) = (0, energies.len());
    let (x_min, x_max) = (min as f64, max as f64);
    let (y_min, y_max) = (
        energies.iter().fold(f64::INFINITY, |a, &b| a.min(b)),
        energies.iter().fold(f64::NEG_INFINITY, |a, &b| a.max(b)),
    );

    // Create the chart with labels and captions
    ChartBuilder::on(&root)
        .x_label_area_size(40)
        .y_label_area_size(40)
        .margin(10)
        .caption("Energies", ("sans-serif", 40.0).into_font())
        .build_cartesian_2d(x_min..x_max, y_min..y_max)
        .map_or_else(
            |error| {
                eprintln!("Could not build chart: {error}");
            },
            |mut chart| {
                // Draw the mesh of the chart
                if let Err(error) = chart.configure_mesh().draw() {
                    eprintln!("Could not draw mesh: {error}");
                }

                // Draw the line series representing the energies
                if let Err(error) = chart.draw_series(LineSeries::new(
                    (min..max).map(|x| (x as f64, energies[x])),
                    &RED,
                )) {
                    eprintln!("Could not draw series: {error}");
                }

                println!("Check the output in file 'energies.png'");
            },
        );
}

// Apply periodic boundary conditions to a point
fn apply_boundary_condition(point: Point) -> Point {
    let mut x = point[0];
    let mut y = point[1];

    // Wrap x-coordinate within the periodic boundary
    if x > PERIODIC_BOUNDARY {
        x -= PERIODIC_BOUNDARY;
    } else if x < 0.0 {
        x += PERIODIC_BOUNDARY;
    }

    // Wrap y-coordinate within the periodic boundary
    if y > PERIODIC_BOUNDARY {
        y -= PERIODIC_BOUNDARY;
    } else if y < 0.0 {
        y += PERIODIC_BOUNDARY;
    }

    [x, y]
}

// Get a new point at a given radius from the current point
fn get_point_at_radius(curr_pos: Point, radius: f64) -> Point {
    let angle = rand::thread_rng().gen::<f64>() * 2.0 * PI;
    let x = angle.cos().mul_add(radius, curr_pos[0]);
    let y = angle.sin().mul_add(radius, curr_pos[1]);
    apply_boundary_condition([x, y])
}

// Calculate the distance between two points using Euclidean distance formula
fn get_distance(point_one: Point, point_two: Point) -> f64 {
    let dx = point_one[0] - point_two[0];
    let dy = point_one[1] - point_two[1];
    dx.hypot(dy)
}

// Calculate the Morse potential function given the distance
fn morse_potential(r: f64) -> f64 {
    2.0f64.mul_add(
        -(-SIGMA * (r - MIN_ATOM_DISTANCE)).exp(),
        (-2.0 * SIGMA * (r - MIN_ATOM_DISTANCE)).exp(),
    )
}

// Calculate the harmonic energy function given the distance
fn harmonic_energy(r: f64) -> f64 {
    K * (r - MAX_ATOM_DISTANCE).powi(2)
}
```

`main.rs`

```rust
use polymer::Polymer;

fn main() {
    let mut polymer = Polymer::default();
    polymer.simulate();
}
```